# Change the number of lines shown in Visual Studio Code's built-in Terminal

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

I'm using the terminal which is integrated in Visual Studio Code. When I scroll up it shows the previous lines, but they are not enough for me. I need to see more lines.

How can I increase the total number of lines that are displayed by the terminal in VS Code?

Answer (score 225, accepted):

There is a way to change number of lines for that you have to go:

> file-->preferences-->configuration

Then, it will open file `settings.json` you should to search `Integrated terminal` and then you search for `terminal.integrated.scrollback` copy and paste this sentence on your user configuration so like this:

[image]

Change numbers of line as you want. That is it.

Comment: Currently (VS Code 1.34) the command to open the settings is File -> Preferences -> Settings. The shortcut is `Ctrl` + `,`.

Comment: Is there a way to set it to infinity?

Comment: Currently, in MacOS, the path is Code -> Preferences -> Settings. Shortcut: Command + ,

   Also, it doesn't look like a JSON (but there may be such a file underlying, though)

Comment: Do you have to restart Vscode for the settings to take effect?

Answer (score 64):

1. Go to `File -> Preferences -> Settings`

[image: terminal_limit_exceaded_menu]

2. Search for `terminal` and open `settings.json`

[image: terminal_limit_exceaded]

3. Add new line to `settings.json`

   ```
     "terminal.integrated.scrollback": 100000000,
   ```

[image: terminal]

Comment: Is that the maximum value? Is there an "infinity" setting?

Comment: Well even if an infinity setting would be more than "100000000", I'd like to know the use case where that is actually necessary :D

Comment: Instead of searching for "terminal" search for "terminal.integrated.scrollback" which takes you straight to the setting, which is always there so doesn't need to be added, and which has initial value 1000.

Comment: Do you have any experience how these changes affect your memory usage?

Answer (score 37):

Visual Studio Code Version 1.47.3, You can do it in Files --> Preferences --> Settings then select Feature/Terminal menu. Find the "Integrated:**Scrollback**" property and change it. Save the settings.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Fastest way just in case:

1. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> (or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> on Mac)
2. Search for `terminal.integrated.scrollback`
3. Update `1000` to something big like `100000000`

[image]