# unique() not showing all values in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to inspect all unique values in a column in a pandas dataframe, however, using `df.column.unique()` only gives the starting and ending values, and values in the middle are hidden with an ellipsis.

I tried

```
mylist =  list(df.column.unique())
mylist
```

which showed more values but not till the end.

---

Edit:

mylist ouput looks like this:

```
 ['PSPC000',
 'LEV12345RTC',
 'LV150390XYZ',
 'WPX-100',
 'FSM-Y2222',
 'FM-YX3',
 'ELB1100',
 'Lx145BP',
 'CE503pxp',
 'Exxy351',
 ...]
```

Comment: Is possible see `mylist` ? It is weird long list is display this way.

Comment: what is your IDE? I know Jupyter would hide so it won;t blow up the browser. try print len(mylist) to confirm you get everything in.

Comment: Check out numpy.set_printoptions docs - not sure if pandas has the equivalent, but there's a numpy array behind pandas series objects https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html

Comment: what's `len(mylist)`? My terminal truncates list longer than 1000. Beside, there's really no point of printing that long list. :-)

Comment: if you really really really want to **print** them all, do `for x in df.column.unique(): print(x)`

Comment: Hi @jezrael please see question edit

Comment: @QuangHoang I think OP can check length of mylist to confirm his code captured the exact number of unique values. How to print them would be a different story

Comment: Hi @QuangHoang len(mylist) is 2490

Comment: Hi @BingWang I'm using VS Code

Comment: Or try `print(*df.column.unique().tolist(), sep='\n')`, maybe help

Comment: OP check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43487492/change-the-number-of-lines-shown-in-visual-studio-codes-built-in-terminal       Maybe you want to output to Excel instead. It is not fun to read 2000 lines in IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
print (df.column.unique().tolist())
```

Comment: I think this works after changing limit setting in VS Code to 0 :) Thank you